# Group and Sum CSV with unknown number of columns

Tags: powershell

Wondering if someone would be able to help me. Problem is that I'm trying to Import , Group, Sum and the Export a CSV. The problem is that my CSV has a unknown number of columns of the following format.

GroupA,GroupB,GroupC,ValueA,ValueB,ValueC,ValueD...

GroupA, B and C are constant and the fields I want to group by - I know the names of these fields in advance. The problem is there are an unknown number of Value columns - all of which I want to Sum (and don't know the names of in advance.)

I'm comfortable getting this code working if I know the name of the Value fields and have a fixed number of Value Fields. But I'm struggling to get code for unknown names and number of columns.

```
$csvImport = import-csv 'C:\input.csv'

$csvGrouped = $csvImport | Group-Object -property GroupA,GroupB,GroupC

$csvGroupedFinal = $csvGrouped | Select-Object @{Name = 'GroupA';Expression={$_.Values[0]}},
        @{Name = 'GroupB';Expression={$_.Values[1]}},
        @{Name = 'GroupC';Expression={$_.Values[2]}},                      
        @{Name = 'ValueA' ;Expression={
                ($_.Group|Measure-Object 'ValueA' -Sum).Sum
        }}

$csvGroupedFinal | Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Example Input Data -

```
GroupA, GroupB, Value A  
Sam, Apple, 10  
Sam, Apple, 20  
Sam, Orange, 50  
Ian, Apple, 15
```

Output Data -

```
GroupA, GroupB, Value A  
Sam, Apple, 30  
Sam, Orange, 50  
Ian, Apple, 15
```

Comment: You should provide sample data of input and expected output. I's unclear to me if you want to sum the columns per row or the totals of all rows per column.

Comment: Totals of all rows per column, have given some sample data. Thankyou!

Comment: Do you have to use powershell? This can be easily done in python.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use Python, I'm in a restricted work environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should work. Pay your attention to the `$FixedNames` variable:

```
$csvImport = @"
Group A,Group B,Value A
sam,apple,10
sam,apple,20
sam,orange,50
ian,apple,15
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$FixedNames  = @('Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C')
# $aux         = ($csvImport|Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).Name  ### sorted (wrong)
$aux         = ($csvImport[0].psobject.Properties).Name                 ### not sorted
$auxGrpNames = @( $aux     | Where-Object {$_    -in $FixedNames})
$auxValNames = @( $aux     | Where-Object {$_ -notin $FixedNames})
$csvGrouped  = $csvImport  | Group-Object -property $auxGrpNames
$csvGroupedFinal = $csvGrouped | 
    ForEach-Object {
        ($_.Name.Replace(', ',','), (($_.Group |
            Measure-Object -Property $auxValNames -Sum
                ).Sum -join ',')) -join ','
    } | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $aux
$csvGroupedFinal
```

Tested likewise for

```
$csvImport = @"
Group A,Group B,Value A,Value B
sam,apple,10,1
sam,apple,20,
sam,orange,50,5
ian,apple,15,51
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

as well as for  more complex data of `Group A,Group B,Group C,Value A,Value B` header.

**Edit** updated according to the [beneficial LotPings' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237887/group-and-sum-csv-with-unknown-number-of-columns/54240239?noredirect=1#comment95331336_54240239).

Comment: Excellent thankyou! Looks like what I'm needing! Thanks again! Will test when back in work.

Comment: @SamDolbear Unfortunately, the solution depends on column names in the original CSV: `Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty` array seems to be sorted by the `Name` property.  Hence, better to obtain variables `$aux`, `$auxGrpNames` and `$auxValNames` in another way (for instance, via parsing the header line)! Hint: read header to a variable using `Get-Content`, split it to the `$aux` variable.

Comment: You could use the not sorted way `$aux = ($csvImport[0].psobject.Properties).Name` to get the header. And to have the first three for sorting `$auxGrpNames = $aux[0..2]`

Answer (score 1):

After importing this script splits the properties (columns) into Groups / Values

- It groups dynamically and sums on only value fields independent of the number
- The input ordering is maintained with a final Select-Object

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\01\17\SO_54237887.ps1

$csvImport = Import-Csv '.\input.csv'

$Cols = ($csvImport[0].psobject.Properties).Name

# get list of group columns by name and wildcard
$GroupCols = $Cols | Where-Object {$_  -like 'Group*'}

# a different approach would be to select a number of leading columns
# $GroupCols = $Cols[0..1]

$ValueCols = $Cols | Where-Object {$_ -notin $GroupCols}
$OutCols = ,'Groups' + $ValueCols

$csvGrouped = $csvImport | Group-Object $GroupCols | ForEach-Object{
    $Props = @{Groups=$_.Name}
    ForEach ($ValCol in $ValueCols){
        $Props.Add($ValCol,($_.Group|Measure-Object $ValCol -Sum).Sum)
    }
    [PSCustomObject]$Props
}

$csvGrouped | Select-Object $OutCols
```

With this sample input file

```
GroupA GroupB ValueA ValueB
------ ------ ------ ------
Sam    Apple  10     15
Sam    Apple  20     25
Sam    Orange 50     75
Ian    Apple  15     20
```

Sample output for any number of Groups and values

```
Groups      ValueA ValueB
------      ------ ------
Sam, Apple      30     40
Sam, Orange     50     75
Ian, Apple      15     20
```

Without any change in code it does process data from Hassans answer too:

```
Groups      ValueA ValueB ValueC
------      ------ ------ ------
Sam, Apple      30      4     20
Sam, Orange     50      4      5
Ian, Apple      15      3      3
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response. It is looping multiple values (of an unknown number) that I am struggling with, if you wouldn't mind demonstrating.

Comment: Sorry. I edited your answer instead of my own answer. Hopefully peer review sees this mistake and cancels the edit. You can also add back your answer.

Comment: @SamDolbear now creating dynamically the properties for [PSCustomObject]

Comment: Thankyou for the edit, looks exactly like what i need!

Comment: So an upvote or split answer or change answer for the above?

Comment: @JosefZ Rewrote the script to use the initial method `.PSObject.Properties` which does **NOT** order properties alphabetically. Instead of relying of `Group` be part of the columns you can now alternatively use the first `n` columns for grouping.

Answer (score 0):

script1.ps1

```
Import-Csv 'input.csv' | `
Group-Object -Property GroupA,GroupB | `
% {$b=$_.name -split ', ';$c=($_.group | `
Measure-Object -Property Value* -Sum).Sum;
[PScustomobject]@{GroupA=$b[0];
GroupB=$b[1];
Sum=($c | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum }}
```

input.csv

```
GroupA, GroupB, ValueA, ValueB, ValueC
Sam, Apple, 10, 1, 10
Sam, Apple, 20, 3, 10
Sam, Orange, 50, 4, 5
Ian, Apple, 15, 3, 3
```

OUTPUT

```
PS D:\coding> .\script1.ps1

GroupA GroupB Sum
------ ------ ---
Sam    Apple   54
Sam    Orange  59
Ian    Apple   21
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately this does the same as the code in my question, but wouldn't work if I want to extend this for an unknown number of 'Values' (Value A, Value B Value C.... ) - which would need to be dynamically determined.

Comment: @SamDolbear See my edited answer above. Different from the accepted answer but maybe useful for now or another time or maybe by someone else.